# Have UITableView row selected rather than just highlighted

Tags: ipad, uitableview

I currently set the selected row of a UITable via
    selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
and as described in the documentation, this does not call 
    tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
so I have set up a selector call to perform this action.

However, the end result is that the row in the table is highlighted, but not selected.  When I touch the highlighted row, the font color changes to white.

Is there a way to not only highlight, but also have the row "selected" so tapping that row again does not result in any changes or updates?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath directly and then scrolling to it. I have this in a UITableViewController and it works fine (and the selection event does not fire again when you tap on it, I just tested it). I'm wondering if there is some other code messing you up.

[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

Comment: I tried your suggestion by itself, and it performs the action associated with selecting the row, but now the row is neither highlighted nor selected.  The table is in editing mode, if that has any effect on what needs to be done.